# get Content-Length of page using curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get Content-Lengtt of a page i have used following code but it shows only `float(-1)` as Content-Length

```
$url="https://www.dropbox.com/favicon.ico";
 $ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");


$content = curl_exec($ch);

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
//echo $content;
// if (strpos($content,"shortcut icon") !== false) {
//     echo 'true';
// }
// else 
// echo "no";
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($curlInfo); echo '</pre>';
```

i'm getting

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(35) "https://www.dropbox.com/favicon.ico"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(404)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(171)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(20)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.812)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.266)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.812)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(1.092)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(15) "108.160.172.206"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(443)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(13) "192.168.1.220"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(59397)
}
```

I'm getting `Content-Length` as a `float(-1)`
I need to get `Content-Length: 347` like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sure way

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");


$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$totalsize = strlen($httpCode);
```

---

```
 $stats = curl_getinfo($ch);

 $size1 = $stats['size_download'];
  $size2 = $stats['download_content_length'];

  if ($size1 > 1 && $size1 > $size2 ){
    $downloadSize = $size1;
    $compression = $totalsize/$size1;
  }
  elseif ($size2 > 1 ){
    $downloadSize = $size2;
    $compression = $totalsize/$size2;
  }
  else {
    $compression = 0;
    $downloadSize = $totalsize;
  }
```

Comment: what is `$stats` var here?

Comment: updated, I had the same problem.  The first way is for sure as long as you are not getting gziped HTML.

Comment: `$totalsize` ?? also not defined

Comment: sorry, I wrote the first then got the second part.

Comment: it works bro `
 $size1 = $stats['size_download'];` this is what i want

Comment: It is not reliable.  Sometimes it does not work.  It took me some time for me to get it correct. I use it a lot.

Comment: so should i use `$downloadsize' instead of `$size1`? @Misunderstood

Comment: I had done this code a while back.  It was also to find the ratio of content to downloaded bytes when the content is gzipped.  Size1 is the number of bytes downloaded.  But the download can be compressed.  I think size is supposed to be the same as totalsize and maybe plus header.   It was very inconstant but I do not remember why.  I do know that it works well this way.  It would help if I knew why.  You can make the request and tell the Server you do not accept compressed data with CURLOPT_ENCODING.